# Xamarin Android - Switch Toggle On/Off Vibration of a notification in AlarmReceiver from MainActivity

Tags: c#, android, notifications, xamarin.android, alarm

> GrayBark says: **"If your activity is killed off and the alarm is fired there will be no activity open to stop the ringtone."** How to????

I have made a simple notification and switch buttons.

**1.** At First, I didn't include switch buttons and it works fine. My code
    is like this one

- **MainActivity**

  ```
      private void MRemindMe_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      //StartReminder 1-6hrs
      intRemind = new Intent(this, typeof(AlarmReceiver));
      pendInt = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(this, 0, intRemind, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);
      alarmManager = (AlarmManager)GetSystemService(AlarmService);
      alarmManager.SetInexactRepeating(AlarmType.ElapsedRealtimeWakeup, SystemClock.ElapsedRealtime() + (1000 * mSeekBar.Progress), (1000 * mSeekBar.Progress), pendInt);
      mCancelNotif.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;

  }
  ```
- **AlarmReceiver**

  ```
  public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
  {

      Intent Intent = new Intent(context, typeof(MainActivity));
      PendingIntent BuildPendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(context, 0, Intent, PendingIntentFlags.CancelCurrent);
      manager = NotificationManager.FromContext(context);
      ISharedPreferences pref = Application.Context.GetSharedPreferences("MyApp", FileCreationMode.Private);
      ISharedPreferencesEditor editor = pref.Edit();

      builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)

          .SetAutoCancel(true)
          .SetContentIntent(BuildPendingIntent)
          .SetContentTitle("Remind Me!")
          .SetTicker("Checklist: Remind Me!")
          .SetContentText("It's time to check your CheckList!")
          .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.Icon)
          .SetVisibility((int)NotificationVisibility.Public)
          .SetFullScreenIntent(BuildPendingIntent, true)
          .SetPriority((int)NotificationPriority.High)
          .SetDefaults((int)NotificationDefaults.All);

      manager.Notify(0, builder.Build());

  }
  ```

**2.**

> And then I finally added a switch toggle button. It worked pretty well when the app is active, minimized.. However, when it's killed, the notification stops and the app is stopped working. **Code is this:**

**AlarmReceiver**

```
        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {

        Intent Intent = new Intent(context, typeof(MainActivity));
        PendingIntent BuildPendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(context, 0, Intent, PendingIntentFlags.CancelCurrent);
        manager = NotificationManager.FromContext(context);
        ISharedPreferences pref = Application.Context.GetSharedPreferences("MyApp", FileCreationMode.Private);
        ISharedPreferencesEditor editor = pref.Edit();

        builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)

            .SetAutoCancel(true)
            .SetContentIntent(BuildPendingIntent)
            .SetContentTitle("Remind Me!")
            .SetTicker("Checklist: Remind Me!")
            .SetContentText("It's time to check your CheckList!")
            .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.Icon)
            .SetVisibility((int)NotificationVisibility.Public)
            .SetFullScreenIntent(BuildPendingIntent, true)
            .SetPriority((int)NotificationPriority.High);
      //added Switch Toggle
        if (MainActivity.mvibrateSW.Checked)
        {
            builder.SetDefaults((int)NotificationDefaults.Vibrate);
        }

        manager.Notify(0, builder.Build());

    }
```

How can I fix this? I can feel that my problem is right under my noses.. also, I've seen a similar problem to this but It's too blurry for me to understand
[How do I stop playing sound by switching between toggle button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29109229/how-do-i-stop-playing-sound-by-switching-between-toggle-button)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I was able to get the answer, Thanks be to God..
Firstly, to understand the problem... my BroadCastReceiver seemed that she depends on MainActivity. As it mentioned above:

> **If Toggle Vibration is Switched then MainActivity is killed BUT the Alarm Fires, therfore Alarm will not fire since BroadCastReceiver can't find whether the Toggle is Switched or Not**

```
To put it Simply

Switch is On (SetVibration = true)
   ↳ Click to Turn On alarm
     ↳ Alarm Service is fired
       ↳ You want to exit App? = Yes
         ↳ Alarm Still Firing (but Where is Toggle? is it On/Off?)
           ↳ Alarm Dies and "Unfortunately, App is not Working"
```

**Therefore** we should make the MainActivity depends on BroadCastReceiver.

> **Solution** is.. make them communicate using Intent Strings.

- MainActivity

  ```
      private void MRemindMe_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      intRemind = new Intent(this, typeof(AlarmReceiver));
      //ToggleSwitch
      if (mvibrateSW.Checked)
      {
          intRemind.PutExtra("vChecked", "On");
      }
      //StartReminder 1-6hrs
      pendInt = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(this, 0, intRemind, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);
      alarmManager = (AlarmManager)GetSystemService(AlarmService);
      alarmManager.SetInexactRepeating(AlarmType.ElapsedRealtimeWakeup, SystemClock.ElapsedRealtime() + (1000 * mSeekBar.Progress), (1000 * mSeekBar.Progress), pendInt);
      mCancelNotif.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
  }
  ```
- AlarmReceiver

  ```
      public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
  {
      Intent Intent = new Intent(context, typeof(MainActivity));
      PendingIntent BuildPendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(context, 0, Intent, PendingIntentFlags.CancelCurrent);
      manager = NotificationManager.FromContext(context);
      ISharedPreferences pref = Application.Context.GetSharedPreferences("MyApp", FileCreationMode.Private);
      ISharedPreferencesEditor editor = pref.Edit();
      string VOn = intent.GetStringExtra("vChecked");
      builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)

          .SetAutoCancel(true)
          .SetContentIntent(BuildPendingIntent)
          .SetContentTitle("Remind Me!")
          .SetTicker("Checklist: Remind Me!")
          .SetContentText("It's time to check your CheckList!")
          .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.Icon)
          .SetVisibility((int)NotificationVisibility.Public)
          .SetFullScreenIntent(BuildPendingIntent, true)
          .SetPriority((int)NotificationPriority.High);

      //Receive Command by String
      string OnVib = intent.GetStringExtra("vChecked");
      if (OnVib == "On")
      {
          builder.SetDefaults((int)NotificationDefaults.Vibrate);
      }
      else
      {
          builder.SetDefaults((int)NotificationDefaults.Lights);
      }
      manager.Notify(0, builder.Build());

  }
  ```